# Spring Security issue 404 error

Tags: spring, spring-security

Web.xml

```
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee 
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">

    <display-name>Spring MVC Application</display-name>
    <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>
    redirect.jsp
    </welcome-file></welcome-file-list>

    <!-- Spring MVC -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
                    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
                </servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>
                  org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
                </listener-class>
    </listener>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            /WEB-INF/mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml,
            /WEB-INF/spring-security.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param>

    <!-- Spring Security -->
    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>
                  org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy
                </filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

</web-app>
```

spring-security.xml

```
   <beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
        xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.0.3.xsd">

        <http auto-config="true">
            <intercept-url pattern="/welcome" access="ROLE_USER" />
        </http>

        <authentication-manager>
          <authentication-provider>
            <user-service>
            <user name="mkyong" password="123456" authorities="ROLE_USER" />
            </user-service>
          </authentication-provider>
        </authentication-manager>

    </beans:beans>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.mkyong.controller" />


    <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix">
            <value>/WEB-INF/pages/</value>
        </property>
        <property name="suffix">
            <value>.jsp</value>
        </property>
    </bean>

</beans>
Controler:

package com.mkyong.controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

@Controller

public class BaseController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/welcome", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String welcome(ModelMap model) {
        System.out.println("am here");

        model.addAttribute("message",
                "Maven Web Project + Spring 3 MVC - welcome()");

        // Spring uses InternalResourceViewResolver and return back index.jsp
        return "index";

    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/welcome/{name}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String welcomeName(@PathVariable String name, ModelMap model) {

        model.addAttribute("message", "Maven Web Project + Spring 3 MVC - "
                + name);
        return "index";

    }

}
```

From re direct page when i re direct ro welcome.html am getting following error

HTTP Status 404 - /Spring-security/welcome

---

type Status report

message /Spring-security/welcome

description The requested resource is not available.

---

Apache Tomcat/7.0.40

Comment: From what you've shown it looks like the URL doesn't exist in your application and the problem isn't realted to Spring Security. Please check the logs and make an effort to debug the issue at the backend, rather than just in the browser. Also explain in your question whether it works if you remove the filter-mapping for springSecurityFilterChain from your web.xml.

Comment: Actually from mykong tutorial its given that when we access welcome page a it will re direct to a login page automatically(which will be automaticaly created by spring-security) but it is giving 404 error.but in web.xml if i change to <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/welcome</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>                                      it's re directing to welcome page.i want the spring-security to display login page when we access welcome page.

Comment: **Dont'load servlet XML with root context!** Not sure why this error is so common. This is probably not the cause of your problem, but it makes Spring a little bit unpredictable when it comes to handling requests.